# jquery popup in salesforce standard detail page

Tags: popup, salesforce

i want to show a jquery popup message after the user creates any record (say Lead ) and lands in the standard lead detail page .... suggestions please ..

also, how to include js files in sidebar component ??

thanks for the responses .

Comment: Are you a developer, or are you just customizing the frontend?

Comment: i do customization as well as development..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this very helpful post by Tehnrd:
http://www.tehnrd.com/show-and-hide-buttons-on-page-layouts/

He details how to include JavaScript files using the sidebar component in a video.

Answer (score 0):

About your popup, I use ModalPopup : http://www.modalpopups.com/demos/0.2/demo.htm
it's pretty simple to use and there is a lot of example in the doc.